# UIScrollView, UITableView and issue with constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, constraints

I have a `UIScrollView` that I want to keep the same size for the iPhone 4 and 5, only the low `UITableView` which should vary the size, of course.

**UIScrollView**
[image: UIScrollView constraints]

**UITableView**
[image: UITableView constraints]

The problem is that when I change the size to **Retina 3.5 Full Screen**, I got this:

[image: The issue]

I could not understand very well how constraints work to get the result I wanted.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have fixed `height` constraint for the `UITableView`, and the `height` of the `UIScrollView` is being calculated taking into account the distances respect the tableView constraint. You have to *PIN* the `height` of the `scrollView`, from the Menu: Editor/Pin/Height.